# Laravel 5.3 Twig rcrowe/twigbridge 0.9.4 extends function not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, twig, laravel-5.3, php-7

I have a problem with extending Twig Templates in Laravel 5.3

The extends function simply does not work, I tried every possible way to extend my base template

> Laravel 5.3.*
>   Twigbridge ^0.9.4
>   OSX

For clarity a simple example I just created

Folder = views/

foo.twig

```
Testing twigs extend function:
<br>
{% block test %}
    Extend does not work :(
{% endblock %}
```

bar.twig

```
{% extends 'foo' %} 

{% block test %}
The extend function works!
{% endblock %}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return View::make('foo');
});

Route::get('/test2', function () {
    return View::make('bar');
});
```

Result : 
[image]

UPDATE: For some reason when I render bar.twig it get's rendered correctly!

Unfortunately this does not work for my real world project. 
Since I'm using more than one block and you can't extend more than one file.
Include works fine tho and I could maybe use include instead... But cmon let's fix this and have that great extends Feature used :)

No exceptions, warnings... whatsoever,

I mean it's Tuesday and I'm tired but srsly, am I missing something obvious here ?!

Any hints on debugging or solutions to this problem or recommendations?

My actual Project:

My Folder Structure:

> views/templates/email/files.twig

I even tried putting everything in

> views/

My test Route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return View::make('templates.email.index',['foo'=>'foo']);
});


Route::get('/test2', function () {
    return View::make('index');
});
```

This does not work:

```
{%  extends 'templates/email/index.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">

                {{ custom }}

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Nor this:

```
{%  extends 'templates.email.index' %}

{% block body %}
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">

                {{ custom }}

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

nor this:

```
{%  extends 'index' %}

{% block body %}
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">

                {{ custom }}

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

nor this, which is suggested by autocompletion:

```
{%  extends 'index.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">

                {{ custom }}

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

my index:

```
{% block header %}
header
{% endblock %}
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
<center>
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                            {% block preHeader %}
                                pre
                            {% endblock %}
                            <!-- // END PREHEADER -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                            {% block body %}
                                body
                            {% endblock %}
                            <!-- // END BODY -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
                            {% block footer %}
                                footer
                            {% endblock %}
                            <!-- // END FOOTER -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting my unextended index template returned...
[image]

Comment: Which path do you visit when you see the unexpected output? `/test` or `/test2`?

Comment: Both give me the same output since I copied all the files also into the views folder

Comment: Guess i'll have to dig into the twigbridge code, just thought maybe someone had a similar issue already